# Generating Entity Getters and Setters in Symfony / Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine, getter-setter

I have the following ORM Symfony entity with only properties :

```
<?php

namespace Evr\HomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ev_article")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="article_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subategory",inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subcategory_id",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $subcategory;


    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=512)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $exclusive_content;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $creation_date;


     /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $views;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $votes;


}
```

I want to generate setters and getters automatically, so I run the following command :

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities Evr/HomeBundle/Entity/Article
```

And everytime I do this, it displays the following error message :

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Class "Evr\HomeBundle\Entity\Article" is not a valid entity or mapped super
   class.



doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

I don't know why it doesn't generate entities, is something wrong in the entity/annotations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to delete this entity and regenerate them with next command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="EvrHomeBundle:Article" --fields="name:string(255) content:text exclusive_content:text creation_date:date views:integer votes:integer"
```

And then add manually:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subategory",inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subcategory_id",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $subcategory;
```

Comment: did you modify something? because the problem persists even with your modification.

Comment: I remove `subcategory` annotation

Comment: Ok, I updated answer, try to generate this entity, please. Is this work?

Comment: No, It doesn't generate getters-setters... You said that you removed the subcategory annotation? it's still there in the answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention, You actually removed an `@` from all the annotations...which desactivates them

Comment: compare with your code. I remove `@` symbol, so it annotation ignored

Comment: But the problem persists, even if you remove annotations

Comment: Ok, I understand. So please try to create empty `ArticleRepository` and add in annotation like in my update

Comment: I created an empty repository, and I added the repository annotation, but in vain...it didn't work yet

Comment: Try to change `ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)`. 255 is maximum

Comment: The problem still persists, even with length=255 .. Anyway, thank you so much for your help @vector (+1)

Comment: It's really strange how the problem isn't solved yet

Comment: Or do you can to delete this entity and regenerate them with `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="EvrHomeBundle:Article" --fields="name:string(255) content:text exclusive_content:text creation_date:date views:integer votes:integer"`

Comment: Okey, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much, it generated the properties, plus the getters and setters.

I'm going now to add the subcategory property.

Comment: Best Answer (You can edit your answer, and put the command in there, so that readers will know what was the solution)

Answer (score 76):

try :

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities EvrHomeBundle:Article
```

If you are using symfony 3.0 or higher then substitue app with bin:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities EvrHomeBundle:Article
```

If you are using symfony 4+ then :

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't matter which command to use, the problem persists.

Comment: hmmm I copied/pasted your entity code and changed the namespace to fit one of my projects and it worked just fine.

Comment: That's really strange !. I have many other classes that have relations with this entity. Like Subcategory, which in turn has a relation with the class Category

Comment: clear you cache and try again. also to detect mapping error execute `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info`

Comment: I cleared cache, and retry : but the problem persists...when I run the command doctrine:mapping:info , it shows 1 message (Found 1 mapped Entities) the mapped entity is the entity User... (In fact I have more than 5 entities in the bundle, even if it showed just 1 mapped entity)

Comment: for Symfony 4+ `bin/console make:entity --regenerate --overwrite App\Entity`
`--overwrite` : to overwrite existing methods (to ignore if not needed)

Answer (score 11):

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

This will generate all the necessary getters and setters automatically into your entity files.

If you want to be specific about the tables, then use this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:"TABLE_NAME"
```

Substitute **"TABLE_NAME"** with your table's name.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to add another answer. This answer is also another working solution, +1 .. I asked this question 3 years ago :) Best !

Comment: Your solution works for me on Symfony 3.4, you +1, can you tell me why Symfony does not document it any where?

Comment: @Dung I have no idea Dung. They should have to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

Mapping import ( from database )

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import 'AppBundle\Entity' yml --path=src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine
```

Generate Entityes from mapping but without getters and setters

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

OR

Generate Entityes from mapping with getters and setters

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity
```

Comment: Thank you, the question is old, but your answer would be of great use +1

Answer (score 3):

Be carreful also to the ORM, to be count to generate getters/setters:

```
/**
 * @var date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="date")

 */
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to add another answer, it works too +1 :) I asked this question 3 years ago. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Thought the missing * is one of the solution

But in my case while creating the entity from command prompt i preferred the Configuration Format to be YML, instead of Annotations.

Now what i am doing is giving mapping commands using annotations, so it is not working.

Try configuring Resources/config/Category.orm.yml as:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
    oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: Product
            mappedBy: Category
```

And Change the Resources/config/Product.orm.yml as:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
    manyToOne:
        category:
            targetEntity: Category
            inversedBy: products
            joinColumn:
                name: category_id
                referenceColumnName: id
```

And i feel it is not a bug but a better understanding!

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to this working solution. I asked this question 3 years ago. Wish you the Best ! +1

Answer (score 1):

Usage:

> orm:generate-entities dest-path

Example in console:

`doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" destination_path`

Source : http://wildlyinaccurate.com/useful-doctrine-2-console-commands/

Comment: Thank you for adding this working solution, I asked this question 3 years ago, Thanks again +1