# Symfony 4 getter setter not generated from existing database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I know that to generate entity from existing database in symfony 4, just execute this command :

```
> php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

but this command dont generate getter setter, just generate variable from column.

and of course I must use some dirty work to create it manually.

may be I missed read the documentation, how to generate entities getter setter from existing database using doctrine symfony 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317022/generating-entity-getters-and-setters-in-symfony-doctrine-orm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To generate entity classes from an existing database you need to ask Doctrine to introspect the database and generate the corresponding metadata files. Metadata files describe the entity class to generate based on table fields.

```
> php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import App\\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity
```

This command will generate new PHP classes with annotation metadata into src/Entity
To generate the missing getter/setter methods (or to create the classes if neceesary), run:

```
> php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

Also check [Official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Answer (score 1):

[DOC says](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#doctrine-generating-getters-and-setters):
"If you prefer to add new properties manually, the make:entity command can generate the getter & setter methods for you:

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

If you make some changes and want to regenerate all getter/setter methods, also pass --overwrite."

Also note that with Symfony 3 (I don't about v4), the `doctrine:generate:entities` did not work with `protected` properties

Answer (score 0):

To do that from an existing database you can use reverse engineering. Follow these steps:

1. configure your database in .env file

2.1. create the entity from your configured database with:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert --from-database annotation ./src/Entity
```

2.2. if you want create the entity for one specific table:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert --from-database --filter="Tablename" annotation ./src/Entity
```

3. if you use vim, you can add getters and setters installing php-getter-setter.vim plugin and typing in each entity:

   :% InsertBothGetterSetter
4. you must add manually in each entity:

   namespace App\Entity;